# Using AJAX, is the request source the web server making the call, or the client browser?

Tags: php, ajax

Wanted to validate something I've come up against regarding the "source" of an AJAX request. I have a website that has functionality that can be accessed both via public internet and local intranet. I have an AJAX call to a php script that can only be accessed while on the intranet (work).

When making the AJAX call, will the source of the request be the web server making the call (will have access because it's on the intranet as well), or would it be the client's browser (public internet) and would fail to load the resource?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the context. Can you clarify what exactly you're coming up against (ie. What specific event triggered you to ask this question?)? A error in the browser maybe ? My first thought is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) related stuff, 
but it's difficult to say with any confidence with the level of detail you've provided here.

Comment: I think @terales answered concisely, but essentially I have a company website that can be access both on the work intranet (requires being on the domain or VPN'ed) and externally over public internet. I'm making an AJAX call to a script that can only be accessed while on the domain. So even though I can get to the actual page because it's externally-accessible, the script it's calling "can't be seen" to the page essentially because of a firewall/segregation. So I was wanting to confirm what is the actual source of the ajax request to validate it's the "domain issue" and not CORS for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX request is performed by the browser, so your client should be inside intranet to get necessary data.